# postgresql copy of rows with index tag

Tags: postgresql, tags, row

Is there any way to have sql query to return split rows. I do not even know how to ask.
Have 'index_tag' below.

```
select event.name, tb_ev.start_time, tb_ev.end_time
from block as tb_ev,event
where location_id in ( 28522 ) 
and tb_ev.event_id=event.id;

name           | start_time | end_time 
---------------+------------+---------- 
 Register #1   | 06:00:00   | 09:00:00
 Register #2   | 11:00:00   | 12:00:00
 Register #3   | 11:00:00   | 14:00:00
```

from 3 rows to 7 rows

```
 name          | start_time | end_time | index_tag
---------------+------------+-------------------- 
 Register #1   | 06:00:00   | 09:00:00 | 06:00:00
 Register #1   | 06:00:00   | 09:00:00 | 07:00:00
 Register #1   | 06:00:00   | 09:00:00 | 08:00:00
 Register #2   | 11:00:00   | 12:00:00 | 11:00:00
 Register #3   | 11:00:00   | 14:00:00 | 11:00:00
 Register #3   | 11:00:00   | 14:00:00 | 12:00:00
 Register #3   | 11:00:00   | 14:00:00 | 13:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, start_time +
          generate_series(0,extract(hour from (end_time - start_time))::int -1)
          * interval '1 hour' as index_tag
FROM block
```

It is a bit ugly, but it works (`generate_series` does not work with `time`. Only `int` or `timestamp`).

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/48ae9/1)

Details about [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)